# LibGdx rectangle with one or more images attached to it

Tags: android, libgdx

Is there a way by which I can draw a colored rectangle (as in `shapeRenderer.filledRect()` ) and attach a image to it?

I know that we can draw a Rectangle using `ShapeRenderer` and then `SpriteBatch.draw()` an image (`Texture`) over it.But then they are two separate objects just one drawn 'over' another.

But is there a way I can combine a rectangle and an image attached to it into one object?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you want? Not clear what you mean by attaching an image to a rectangle.

Comment: How to you want to combine them? If you draw one object over the other you won't see the object underneath the other, if it is not transparent. If you want to "tint" the image you can use `SpriteBatch#setColor` which applies this color to all things drawn with this `SpriteBatch`.